# An error happened during template parsing

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

**Code**
**Order**

```
public class Order {
    private String id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
//get set constructor constructors
}
```

**IndexController**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**OrderController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {
    private final OrderService orderService;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<String> list(Model model) {
        var orders = orderService.orders();
        model.addAttribute("orders", orders);
        return Mono.just("orders/list");
    }
}
```

**OrderGenerator**

```
public class OrderGenerator {
    public Order generate() {
        var amount = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(1000.00);
        return new Order(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
    }
}
```

**OrderService**

```
@Service
public class OrderService {

    private final Map<String, Order> orders = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(10);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        var generator = new OrderGenerator();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            var order = generator.generate();
            orders.put(order.getId(), order);
        }
    }

    public Mono<Order> findById(String id) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(orders.get(id));
    }

    public Mono<Order> save(Mono<Order> order) {
        return order.map(this::save);
    }

    private Order save(Order order) {
        orders.put(order.getId(), order);
        return order;
    }

    public Flux<Order> orders() {
        return Flux.fromIterable(orders.values()).delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(128));
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Orders</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="order : ${orders}">
                <td th:text="${order.id}"></td>
                <td th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(order.amount)}"
                    style="text-align: right"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**error**

An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/orders/list.html]")

Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "order.id" (template: "orders/list" - line 19, col 9)

EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly' - maybe not public or not valid?

I do not how to solve the problem, i hope you can help me.thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add reactive primitives like Flux and Mono as `IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable`.

```
IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable reactiveDataDrivenMode =
            new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable(orders);

    model.addAttribute("orders", reactiveDataDrivenMode);
```

Comment: thank for you reply. but it does not working . i change list function on controller.

Comment: thanks , i know where error is. i import spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-webflux in pom.xml. i am crazy

Answer (score 0):

check that you are using spring-boot-starter-webflux  instead of spring-boot-starter-web